# datastax uninstall or re-run install

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax

I installed DSE 4.5 on 3 nodes in AWS. The cluster came up successfully originally. I made some changes to the endpoint snitch on cassandra.yaml and now the cluster no longer comes up. I changed back to the original cassandra.yaml but the nodes still won't start. There's no data as I am at the beginning of a project.

Here's my question - Is there a way to re-run the installer to recreate each node? Otherwise, I will delete the instances and start over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given where you are in your project, the easiest is probably to just start from scratch. The standalone installer creates an uninstaller in the installation directory. If you run that and choose full uninstall it will wipe all configuration/data files as well as the binaries.

Thanks,
Sven